# Почему не работает код в VS

Tags: c#

```
        RegistryKey hklm = Registry.LocalMachine;
        RegistryKey helloKey = hklm.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        helloKey.SetValue("Service.Host", "ff");
        hklm.Close();
        helloKey.Close();
```

Компилирую его стандартным компилятором NET который поставляется с фреймворкрм и все работает,раздел создается,а если компилировать из под студии то ничего не создается и никаких ошибок?

UPD. В общем как оказалось этот код скомпилированный на VS не работает только на моей семерке,на десятке виртуалке он работает...Как так...А если его компилировать на csc.exe от net то все работает и у меня и везде...

UPD.ПРОБЛЕМУ РЕШИЛ,оказалось csc по дефолту делает сборку разрядности винды у меня x64,а в студии стояла разрядность "x32 предпочтительнее" по этому нормально сборка не могла работать с реестром хоть и не было ошибок и исключений.Кто не знал учтите,сборка не может нормально работать с реестром если разрядность не как у винды.

Comment: Какой именно фреймворк (версия)? Какая именно студия? Проект какого типа?

Comment: Alexander Petrov,последняя студия(2017) последний фреймворк(4.8) консольный проект.Я все версии фреймворка испробовал

Comment: Вы вполне можете написать ответ. Также обратите внимание [RegistryView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryview?view=netframework-4.8)